# ANSI escape characters in gprolog

Tags: prolog, escaping, iso-prolog

Trying to print bold and underlined text in prolog but can't write them

```
 write('\033[1mbold\033[0m')
```

Makes this (expected) error:

```
 syntax error: \ expected in \constant\ sequence
```

What's the correct way to do it with `gprolog` ? Maybe with `format` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
write('\33\[1mbold\33\[0m').
```

That is, octal  escape sequences (and hexadecimal which start with `\x`) need to be closed with a `\` too. En revanche, a leading zero is not required, but possible. This is in no way specific to GNU, in fact, probably all systems close to ISO Prolog have it.